# Magento2: Get Bundle product Id in overridden function

Tags: magento2, price, bundled-product

I have overridden **getValue()** function of **Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice**

So how can i get the bundle product Id in this function.
When I try to get the bundle product id it giving me the simple product id of that bundle product.

**Note :** I have tried **getParentIdsByChild()** but it giving all the parent ids instead of current parent Id

Comment: Have you try to get it from current product registry?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, yes but its not working on product listing page